# About the primitives of $\frac1{a^2 + (2x)^2}$

Tags: integration

So I was to find the integral $\int^{\frac{3}{2}}_0\frac{1}{9+4x^2}dx$

I noticed that the denominator is equal to $3^2+(2x)^2$ and thought I could use the integral $\int\frac{1}{a^2+x^2}dx = \frac{1}{a}arctan(\frac{x}{a}) + C$.

Hence, $[\frac{1}{3}arctan(\frac{2z}{3})]^{3/2}_0 = \frac{\pi}{12} - 0 =  \frac{\pi}{12}$

The textbooks answer was $\frac{\pi}{24}$. It also gives a solution by dividing the denominator and taking $\frac{1}{4}$ outside of the integral before integrating so the denominator is $\frac{9}{4} + x^2 = (\frac{3}{2})^2 + x^2$.

So my question is why does the integral for $\int\frac{1}{a^2+x^2}dx$ not work when instead of ${x^2}$ you have ${(kx)^2}$ for some constant k?

Comment: Because of the chain rule. $kx$ has a derivative $k$ that needs to taken in account for. Try a u-sub on your integral $4x=t$ and rewrite the integral to see...

Comment: $$\int\frac{dx}{a^2+k^2x^2}\stackrel{(kx=at)}{=}\int\frac{dt}{ak(1+t^2)}=\frac1{ak}\arctan(t)+C=\frac1{ak}\arctan\left(\frac{kx}a\right)+C$$

Answer (score 1):

The same reason why $\sin (2x)$ is not an anti-derivative (= *primitive function*) of $\cos (2x)$, although $\sin (x)$ *is* an anti-derivative of $\cos (x)$.

To see what happens, you can use the substitution method for integrals (let $t = kx$ etc).

Or the other way around: because the **chain rule** for derivatives would produce an extra factor $2$ (in the case of $2x$) or generally $k$ (in the case of $kx$).